# Distorted arabic font when trying to make text follow the path using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arabic, tikz-decorations

I need to make Arabic text follow some curved path using TikZ. This is the sample code I am using:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic} 

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,Path=./fonts/]{GretaArabicAR-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\arr}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,Path=./fonts/]{GretaArabicAR-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\arb}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,Path=./fonts/]{GretaArabicAR-Bold}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tekst}{\fontsize{20pt}{20}\selectfont\textarabic{\arb{إلى حبيبي لوكاس"!}}}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,
text={|\fontsize{20pt}{20}\selectfont\arb|إلى حبيبي لوكاس"!},
raise=-1pt}}](58mm, -64mm)to[bend left=35] (152mm, -36mm){};     
\end{tikzpicture}



Some latin text and inline arabic:

\textarabic{\arb\fontsize{20pt}{20}\selectfont{إلى حبيبي لوكاس"!}}


\end{document}
```

When I compile it, there are two problems:

1. The characters are distorted, like it is not the same font (take a close look at the character ل)
2. I cannot force RTL to the text itself. It just ignores me.

Here are the sample PDF i am getting and the font I'm trying to use: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qx3yzfaavf8io9j/AACEdkMKQFaPr-oNj8BOQ2iXa?dl=0

Can someone shed some light on these issues I am experiencing?

Comment: Worst case you can put each letter into a separate \hbox.